# Content not being found on my DEV web server when it is in fact actually there

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, iis, master-pages

I'm having an issue trying to resolve references in my masterpage.

As you can see by the accompanying screen shot, the issues state that the files cannot be found.

But after checking the corresponding filepath that says where it can't be found, it is indeed physically there. I checked out the properties of the files to see if there was anything out of the ordinary, but is not.

Can someone please help me determine why these files cannot be found on my IIS server?

[image]

Comment: The type (in the console) where the js can't be found says "text/html". I tried putting in the javascript type, but still did not help: <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: btw, all the files that cannot be found are JS files. Do I need to do anything else to specify that on the page or the web server that the files are JS files?

Comment: Tried the following and still didn't help: <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules in web.config that could be interfering? Also check the folder permissions on the Scripts folder. Also, check the mime types, make sure js is in there.